# iPhone sending data to and retrieving data from Google Apps?

Tags: iphone, google-apps

I've seen a couple of iPhone applications that have the functionality to export data to a Google Apps document or spreadsheet.  I would like to add similar functionality to my iPhone app.  Is there an API for that?  How about the other direction - is there a way to get data (say a CSV file) from a Google Apps spreadsheet?

If there isn't one of those, is there a way to directly import a SQLite dump file in iTunes?

Background: the app I'm writing deals with a large number of records, possibly thousands, and rather than expecting people to enter them on that tiny little keyboard, I'd like to be able to take data entered on a real computer.  Plus, this iPhone app is replacing a Palm app that I already use, which I have entered hundreds of records, but which has the ability to produce a CSV file.

Comment: Jeez, I can't believe that only got one answer. Was it that simple, or do people just not care about iphone + google?:)

Comment: I'm surprised too.  I was hoping there would be more info about downloading and parsing google docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Google's Doc List API regarding [uploading documents](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingDocs). That same API reference has information on retrieving documents.

Here's a [sample of document uploading](http://googledataapis.blogspot.com/2008/01/easily-upload-your-documents-to-google.html) from Google.